# Powershell, Run For Each Loop and Export Output to .csv

Tags: csv, powershell, exchange-server

I'm pretty new to Powershell so I was wondering if I could get some help...

I'm running this code down here in order to loop through each distribution group to pull distribution group members.

```
Foreach ($objDistributionGroup in $objDistributionGroups) 
{     

    write-host "Processing $($objDistributionGroup.DisplayName)..." 

    #Get members of this group 
    $objDGMembers = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $($objDistributionGroup.PrimarySmtpAddress) 

    write-host "Found $($objDGMembers.Count) members..." 

    #Iterate through each member 
    Foreach ($objMember in $objDGMembers) 
    { 
        Out-File -FilePath $OutputFile = "C:\DistributionGroupWithMembers" -InputObject "$($objDistributionGroup.DisplayName),$($objDistributionGroup.PrimarySMTPAddress),$($objMember.DisplayName),$($objMember.PrimarySMTPAddress),$($objMember.RecipientType)" -Encoding UTF8 -append 
        write-host "`t$($objDistributionGroup.DisplayName),$($objDistributionGroup.PrimarySMTPAddress),$($objMember.DisplayName),$($objMember.PrimarySMTPAddress),$($objMember.RecipientType)"
    } 
}
```

I get this error:

> Out-File : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'FilePath' because it is
>   null. At line:14 char:22

How do I properly set the Output location?  Ultimately, I want to save the output to a .csv for me to open.

Comment: If you want to use a variable for the value of the file, you either need to assign `$OutputFile` earlier(preferably outside the `Foreach` so you only need to set it one time), You could also enclose it in parenthesis so the assignment operation is performed first: `Out-File -FilePath ($OutputFile = "C:\DistributionGroupWithMembers")`. Alternatively, if you wanted to use the displayname for each group: `Out-File -FilePath "C:\DistributionGroupWithMembers\$_.DisplayName.txt"` Also, outputting directly to a file in C:\ often doesn't work unless you're running PowerShell as admin.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be how you assign `$OutputFile = "C:\DistributionGroupWithMembers"` in the parameters. Try something like this:

```
Out-File -FilePath "C:\DistributionGroupWithMembers.csv" -InputObject ....
```

You could also potentially look at using `Export-Csv` or `ConvertTo-Csv`, but since you seperate values with `,` inside InputObject this might be fine.